# How to get Exif data from downloaded image

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, ios6

In my application , I need to download the image from particular URL Link and assign that to `UIImageView`. I do not store that image to my Library, then in this case how can I get the **Exif data of this image** (like `EXIF_TAG_CREATE_DATE` , `EXIF_TAG_ARTIST`, etc) in my app?

Comment: Does this help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7590741/using-cgimageproperties-to-get-exif-properties

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
try this  

NSError *error = nil;
NSDictionary *attributes = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] 
    attributesOfItemAtPath:@"imagePath" error:&error];

if (!error) 
{
    NSLog(@"file attributes : %@",attributes);
}

and this is the result :

NSFileCreationDate = "2013-05-28 09:29:37 +0000";
NSFileExtensionHidden = 0;
NSFileGroupOwnerAccountID = 20;
NSFileGroupOwnerAccountName = staff;
NSFileModificationDate = "2013-05-28 09:29:37 +0000";
NSFileOwnerAccountID = 502;
NSFileOwnerAccountName = lerhan;
NSFilePosixPermissions = 420;
NSFileReferenceCount = 1;
NSFileSize = 1494;
NSFileSystemFileNumber = 46795419;
NSFileSystemNumber = 234881026;
NSFileType = NSFileTypeRegular;

to access any data type NSLog(@"file creation date : %@",[attributes objectForKey:@"NSFileCreationDate"]);
```

Comment: What has the file attributes got to do with it?

Comment: Its returns the attributes to nil value while i am using share extension

Comment: This is not the EXIF metadata. This is the file metadata, they are different. The creation date here is not equal to the taken on date of the photo, for example.

Answer (score 5):

### Accessing image properties, such as image height and width, DPI, EXIF data, etc., via ImageIO

```
CFURLRef url = CFURLCreateFromFileSystemRepresentation (kCFAllocatorDefault, (const UInt8 *)inputFileName, strlen(inputFileName), false);

if (!url) {
   printf ("* * Bad input file path\n"); 
}

CGImageSourceRef myImageSource;

myImageSource = CGImageSourceCreateWithURL(url, NULL);

CFDictionaryRef imagePropertiesDictionary;

imagePropertiesDictionary = CGImageSourceCopyPropertiesAtIndex(myImageSource,0, NULL);

CFNumberRef imageWidth = (CFNumberRef)CFDictionaryGetValue(imagePropertiesDictionary, kCGImagePropertyPixelWidth);
CFNumberRef imageHeight = (CFNumberRef)CFDictionaryGetValue(imagePropertiesDictionary, kCGImagePropertyPixelHeight);

int w = 0;
int h = 0;

CFNumberGetValue(imageWidth, kCFNumberIntType, &w);
CFNumberGetValue(imageHeight, kCFNumberIntType, &h);

CFRelease(imagePropertiesDictionary);
CFRelease(myImageSource);

printf("Image Width: %d\n",w);
printf("Image Height: %d\n",h);
```

( source: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#qa/qa1654/_index.html )

```
    NSString *myPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"IMG_2733" ofType:@"JPG"];
    NSURL *myURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:myPath];
    CGImageSourceRef mySourceRef = CGImageSourceCreateWithURL((CFURLRef)myURL, NULL);
    NSDictionary *myMetadata = (NSDictionary *) CGImageSourceCopyPropertiesAtIndex(mySourceRef,0,NULL);
    NSDictionary *exifDic = [myMetadata objectForKey:(NSString *)kCGImagePropertyExifDictionary];
    NSDictionary *tiffDic = [myMetadata objectForKey:(NSString *)kCGImagePropertyTIFFDictionary];
    NSLog(@"exifDic properties: %@", myMetadata); //all data
    float rawShutterSpeed = [[exifDic objectForKey:(NSString *)kCGImagePropertyExifExposureTime] floatValue];
    int decShutterSpeed = (1 / rawShutterSpeed);
    NSLog(@"Camera %@",[tiffDic objectForKey:(NSString *)kCGImagePropertyTIFFModel]);
    NSLog(@"Focal Length %@mm",[exifDic objectForKey:(NSString *)kCGImagePropertyExifFocalLength]);
    NSLog(@"Shutter Speed %@", [NSString stringWithFormat:@"1/%d", decShutterSpeed]);
    NSLog(@"Aperture f/%@",[exifDic objectForKey:(NSString *)kCGImagePropertyExifFNumber]);
    NSNumber *ExifISOSpeed  = [[exifDic objectForKey:(NSString*)kCGImagePropertyExifISOSpeedRatings] objectAtIndex:0];
    NSLog(@"ISO %i",[ExifISOSpeed integerValue]);
    NSLog(@"Taken %@",[exifDic objectForKey:(NSString*)kCGImagePropertyExifDateTimeDigitized]);
```

( source: http://blog.depicus.com/index.php/2011/05/07/getting-exif-data-from-images-on-ios/ )

### Accessing EXIF properties via the open source (but outdated) iphone-exif library

```
NSData* theImageData = UIImageRepresentation(anImage,1.0);
EXFJpeg* jpegScanner = [[EXFJpeg alloc] init];
[jpegScanner scanImageData: theImageData];
EXFMetaData* exifData = jpegScanner.exifMetaData; EXFJFIF* jfif =
jpegScanner.jfif;
id tagValue = [exifData tagValue: aTagId];
```

( source: http://code.google.com/p/iphone-exif/ )